# Advantages of list initialization in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, list-initialization

So far I've found following uses of [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (a.k.a. uniform initialization).

1) Before Introduction was list initialization feature

```
int a=3.3f;   // ouch fractional part is automatically truncated
```

But in C++11

```
int a{3.3f};  // compiler error no implicit narrowing conversion allowed
```

2) Dynamic array elements can be initialized statically.
   See for example this program is invalid in C++03 but valid since C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int* p=new int[3]{3,4,5};
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        std::cout<<p[i]<<' ';
    delete[] p;
}
```

3) It solves [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) problem

It would be better if you tell me other advantages of list initialization. Are there still any advantages of list initialization except above 3?

Your answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: You stacked-crooked.com link is broken, you are just linking directly to the site not to your example.

Comment: @mattnewport: fixed it. See updated question !!!

Comment: Note a [narrowing conversion is ill-formed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27508570/1708801) which requires a diagnostic not an error. Your question seems to imply is requires an error.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour consistent with the C++ Standard, which in examples uses "error: ..." when documenting ill-formed code

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb indeed, but most compilers will use error to mean a failure as opposed to warning, unless using `-Werror` or something similar. Note, the comment does say *compiler error*.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: As far as I know, the standard does not explicitly mention the idea of compiler errors versus compiler warnings. Which things are errors vs. warnings is left up to the implementation, and usually configurable by the user. The compiler is never *required* not to emit code in some case, it is only required to emit code conforming to the spec for well-formed programs, and to emit diagnostics in some other cases. And in case of undefined behavior it can emit whatever it wants.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: so you mean to say every C++ compiler that supports C++11 isn't necessarily to give an compile time error for int a{3.3f}; right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A significant advantage you don't mention is its usefulness in template metaprogramming, where you can now compute something using templates, and then, in a constexpr function, expand some template data structure and store the results in an array.

See for instance here: [Populate An Array Using Constexpr at Compile-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313980/populate-an-array-using-constexpr-at-compile-time)

In the code:

```
template<unsigned... Is>
constexpr Table MagicFunction(seq<Is...>){
  return {{ whichCategory(Is)... }};
}
```

I don't think there was any way to do anything like that prior to C++11.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you consider it a separate feature but the same syntax is also used to overload constructors on `std::initializer_list` which allows you to initialize STL containers directly:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> m{{"foo", "bar"}, {"apple", "pear"}};
std::cout << m["foo"] << std::endl;
```

Comment: With the slight *disadvantage* that  `std::vector<int> v(1, 2);` is different from `std::vector<int> v{1, 2};`.